# sharedpreferences value not updated

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a Sharedpreferences to check if the user has activated the pro section with InAppPurchase and I check it every time Mainactivity is opens, like this:

```
SharedPreferences s = c.getSharedPreferences("app" , MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = s.getString(key , " ");
Log.i("myapp" , value);
```

and if some one tries to change the value manually my app warns him .so I tried to test my app's security and changed the value manually with text editor from `data/data/com.myapp.package/shared_prefs/` let's say the value was `39m49ur3`.I changed it a to `87mjr83`.Then I started the app and the value from the logs stil was `39m49ur3` . I closed the app and started it again but no change was seen except when I clear the RAM of my device then start the app  , finally then the value I got from the logs is what really is in the `shared_prefs` folder.
What can I do about this?

Comment: it would be better if u post the part of the code where ur updating the value

Answer (score 0):

Save like this,

```
SharedPreferences pref = c.getSharedPreferences("app", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("myapp", "string value"); 
editor.commit();
```

Get Like this,

```
pref.getString("myapp", null);
```

Comment: thanks but I know these already ,  My value just isn't updating when I change it manually with text editor from the file manager.

Comment: @PooyaTaheri your device is rooted or not ?

Comment: of cource , otherwise I wouldnt be able to change the sharedpreferences manually

Comment: Perfect, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

//to save String in shared preferences

```
 public void put(String key, String value) {
    mSharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
}
```

//to get value from shared preferences

```
 public String get(String key, String defaultValue) {
    return mSharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Consider using apply() instead; commit writes its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas apply will handle it in the background.

Comment: thanks but I know these already ,  My value just isn't updating when I change it manually with text editor

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
editor.apply();
```

Instead of

```
editor.commit();
```

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures.

Comment: thanks but I know these already , and I dont have problem putting the value , my problem is with getting the value